# How would someone know, when to pass an object as an argument to functions

Tags: python, python-2.7, functional-programming

Let say I have a string

```
my_str = "Hello World"
func1 = getattr(__builtins__, 'len')
func1
<built-in function len>
func1()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: len() takes exactly one argument (0 given)

func1(my_str)
11
```

In func1 I have to pass the ***my_str*** object in ***func1*** to get the results, but if I do something like this

```
func2 = getattr(my_str, 'replace')
func2
<built-in method replace of str object at 0x102d83cc0>

func2()
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: replace() takes at least 2 arguments (0 given)

func2("Hello", "Yello")
'Yello World'
```

Here func2, is a ***built-in methed of my_str object*** and I don't have to pass my_str object.

Given 2 objects ***func1*** and ***func2*** I would like to know is their a way to differentiate between these 2 functions during run-time

Comment: Which difference is it that you are interested in?

Comment: @LutzHorn When to pass my_str as an argument and when not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be solved if following question can answered.

whether a function/method is a part of an object or not?
In given example, func1 is an independent function and func2 is a method of 'str' object.

"`__self__`" attribute can be used to answer that.

```
my_str = "Hello World"
func1 = getattr(__builtins__, 'len')
func1
func1.__self__ # is empty

func2 = getattr(my_str, 'replace')
func2
func2.__self__ # it is non-empty
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is potentially much more complicated than you describe. functions can also take optional arguments (providing default values), a variable number of positional arguments (`*args`), keyword arguments (`**kwargs`).

To inspect function's arg-spec, you can use [`inspect.getargspec`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec):

```
import inspect
def f(): pass
def g(x): pass
inspect.getargspec(f)
=> ArgSpec(args=[], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None)
inspect.getargspec(g)
=> ArgSpec(args=['x'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None)
```

This clearly show the differences between the signatures of `f` and `g`.

Comment: inspect.getargspec doesn't work for built-in functions, see http://bugs.python.org/issue1748064